# Printing the array elements sorted by repetition

Tags: algorithms, sorting, arrays

I just can't figure this question out:

Given an array of N elements, its values range are from 0 to 100.
Write a function that prints the array's elements sorted by repetition.

Time complexity : O(N)

---

For example: Array: [20,60,10,80,100,0,20,20,30,35]

The function should print: 20 20 20 60 10 80 100 0 30 35

Comment: Just confirming - you mean "print the elements of the array in the same relative order they appear, but move all duplicated elements so that they all appear along with their first copy?"

Comment: @templatetypedef "Sorted" suggests that the element that every element that is in the array $k$ times must be output before any element that's only in it $k-1$ times. DopeGainz, please clarify the question to state exactly waht you mean by "sorted by repetition".

Comment: Hello! We discourage posts that simply state a problem out of context, and expect the community to solve it. Assuming you tried to solve it yourself and got stuck, it may be helpful if you wrote your thoughts and what you could not figure out. It will definitely draw more answers to your post. Until then, the question will be voted to be closed / downvoted. You may also want to check out our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599/), or use the search engine of this site to find similar questions that were already answered.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use some arrays of length 100, and the fact that 100 is a constant.